# Is the sequence $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{\log n}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How should I decide if the following sequence is convergent or divergent?

$$a_n = \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{\log n}$$
I would appreciate any approach. Thanks.

---

I was misunderstood series and sequence so I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You're asked to decide if a certain *sequence* converges.  The Ratio Test applies to *series.*

Comment: By looking at the graph of $yx=1$, you can check that $$\log n \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k \leqslant 1+\log n $$
for each $n\geqslant 1$, so that the limit of the sequence $a_n$ is $1$.

Comment: The term test is sufficient...

Comment: Are you really being asked if $\sum a_n$ converges? Or if the sequence $a_n$ converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [integral test proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), you know that
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\leq 1+\int_1^{n}\frac{dx}{x}
$$
Since $\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(x)+C$, you can calculate that the limit converges by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use comparison with integrals.  Since $f(x)=1/x$ is monotone,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k 
\ge \int_1^{n+1} \frac 1x dx
=\log (n+1)
$$
and similarly
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k
\le 1 + \int_1^n \frac 1xdx
=1+\log n
$$
Therefore $a_n$ is between $\log(n+1)/\log n$ and $1+1/\log n$ and must converge to 1.

Actually you can show a stronger result:  the difference between the $\log n$ and the sum converges to a constant, called Euler–Mascheroni constant.